# Обучение сети встречного распростронения

Tags: нейронные-сети

В книге Уоссернама [1](http://neuronets.chat.ru/nets.html) про обучение сетей встречного распростронения (слоя Кохонена) написано, что есть алгоритм оптимизации, при котором все(!?!) веса задают равными 1/sqrt(n), где n - количество входов/компонент векторов. Как же искать нейрон-победитель для обучения? Ведь если все веса всех нейноров равны, от и на выходе у всех будет одно и то же значение!